# Ubuntu won't detect boot partition for Kali Linux

Tags: partitioning, boot-partition

I have Kali Linux installed alongside Ubuntu, and when I run `update-grub` it detects it but does not add it to the grub config file. Also when I run `blkid` it doesn't show the `/boot` partition for Kali. When I run GParted it does, as `/dev/sdb3`.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2Sc44Wri

Comment: `/dev/sdb3` is the `/boot` for Kali Linux. When I try to mount it with `sudo mount /dev/sdb3` it says `mount: can't find /dev/sdb3 in fstab`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try up boot repair from this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
and if didn t work try to see the report to know the the exact problem